# Typing Immutable.js with Redux and alternatives

Tags: typescript, redux, immutable.js

I've just incorporated Immutable.js into a small React/Redux + Typescript project and due to the typing problems I'm really unsure whether it's the way to go. I'd like to hear opinions of more experienced programmers.

The obvious benefit of Immutable.js is that it keeps your state immutable for you.

The drawback is the absolute lack of typing. `getIn` and `setIn` are your primary means to interact with data, especially your store's data. The more nested it is, the more painful and dangerous it gets. Moreover, changing store structure will not produce any errors anymore - you will be left with tons of `setIn`s scattered all through the project, each of which you need to find and fix. Refactoring becomes insanely dangerous.

I've heard multiple people praise Immutable.js, but is it really worth all the pain resulting from the lack of typing?

What are the alternative solutions? Why would/wouldn't I use a library of some kind to deep clone the state at the start of every reducer?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer not to have complex nested Redux state.
Here you find an article that describes how you can normalize your data structure: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape

Note the following explanation:

> Notice that the structure of the data is a bit complex, and some of
> the data is repeated. This is a concern for several reasons:
> ...
>
> - Nested data means that the corresponding reducer logic has to be more nested and therefore more complex. In particular, trying to update a deeply nested field can become very ugly very fast.
>
> Because of this, the recommended approach to managing relational or nested data in a Redux store is to treat a portion of your store as if it were a database, and keep that data in a normalized form.

Another popular library is https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper